# Animate list items on removal of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, smooth-scrolling

I have implemented a scrolling list that works by removing the top element and appends it to the bottom. This gives it the effect of scrolling infinitely. The problem is that by removing the < li >, all the elements shift up in a kind of jerky way (to be clear, I do want them to shift up, but I want it to be smooth).

Is there any way I can animate this change in the DOM so that it appears that the items slide into their new places, rather than have it jerk into place? Here is some code to show how it is currently implemented:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>

// Called every few seconds
function scrollList () {
  var top = $('li').first();
  $('li').first().remove();
  $('ul').append(top);
}
```

Here's a link to JS Fiddle that shows current behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/gak7u1r8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
setInterval(function () {
  var top = $('li').first();
    top.hide(200, function() {
      top.remove();
      $('ul').append(top);
      top.show(200);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This worked surprisingly well. I actually knew about this but assumed it would wait until the animation was done, and then jump the other elements. They slid into place nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback to do something after [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/):

```js
setInterval(scrollList, 1000);

function scrollList () {
  var top = $('li').first();
  $('li').first().slideUp(400, function() {
    $('ul').append(top);
    top.show();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would animate top position (`linear` or `swing`) as here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gak7u1r8/3/

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1em;
    background: none #efefef;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
li {
    line-height: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
function scrollList () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('ul').animate({top: -25}, 500, 'swing', function() {
            $('ul').css({'top': '0'}).append( $('li').first() );
            scrollList();
        });
    }, 2000);
};
scrollList();
```